# Wordpress jetpack infinite scroll and Isotope

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

At the moment i am busy creating a new wordpress template, where i try to implement Infinite-Scroll (which is part of "Jetpack") in combination with Isotope.
The project Homepage is: http://184990.webhosting29.1blu.de/fashion/.

This is my code for isotope:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var $container = jQuery('#content').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: '.isotope-item',
        gutter: 20,
        }
    });
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
    $container.isotope('layout');
    });     
}); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery(document.body).on( 'post-load', function () {
    alert("New elements added.");
    });
});
</script>
```

As you can see when new elements are added by infinite scroll i set up a jquery alert ("new elements added")

I added this to my functions.php:

```
    //Infinite Scroll
    add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
    'container' => 'content',
    'wrapper' => false,
    'footer' => 'page',
      ) );
```

**The problem** is i have no idea how to make isotope recognize the newly added elements and relayout properly.

Would be great if somebody could help me out!

Comment: The page you link to has code for masonry, not isotope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the job:

```
<script>
  jQuery(function($){

    var $container = jQuery('#content');
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
        columnWidth: '.isotope-item',
        gutter: 20,
      });

    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $container.masonry();
    });

    $container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '#nav-below',    // selector for the paged navigation 
      nextSelector : '#nav-below a.next',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
      itemSelector : '.isotope-item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
      loading: {
          speed: 0,
          msgText: 'Lade weitere...',
          finishedMsg: 'Du bist am Ende angelangt.',
          img: 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAHAAACH5BAUAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==',
        }
      },
      // trigger Masonry as a callback
      function( newElements ) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
          // show elems now they're ready
          $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
          $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
        });
      }
    );

  });
</script>
```

but i had to use masonry instead of isotope.